# Is it okay to ask friends to contribute to an Area 51 proposal?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51

I started a proposal on Area 51, Latin Hebrew, and then I went to some friends and relatives, who were originally not interested in the Hebrew Language, to tell them about this new proposal.

I asked them if it would be imaginable for them to take some time and to think up some questions for this subject and to post them on Area 51 to help me with the proposal. Some have done so, and others plan to.

I know that this means the proposal does - in some aspect - not reflect the reality, but it helps getting started. And maybe some of them might get really interested, either in "Latin Hebrew" or "Stack Exchange" as a Q&A site in general.

For me it can be compared to a businessman who sells his first products to friends and relatives. This also does not reflect how the product will do in the future, since most maybe bought it because of him. But it helps to get him going.

Is this acceptable, to ask people I know to help out with my Area 51 proposal? If not, I will stop.

Comment: There is a link on Area51 proposals so you can "share with friends" by social media .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course!

Part of the way Stack Exchange finds new users is through having existing users point friends and family at the site and say, "Here's this site I use. I like it a lot and think you'd like it, too. Come join me!"

The system is set up with pretty high bars, so unless you have 300 family members who all become really interested in this proposal, you're not going to do much harm but you may do a lot of good - a proposal with 20 followers and 30 questions looks more attractive to others than one with 1-2 followers and three questions.

We've had cases of companies flooding an Area 51 proposal in the past to force it into existence. This is bad. It's also really obvious and, even if it got through definition phase, it wouldn't get past commitment phase because none of the users had sufficient reputation on the network to fill the requirements. They were banned from ever proposing a site for their products again.

In fact, shortly after posting this answer, I found an example of it:

[image: Closed proposal for false interest]

You can see the CM message closing the proposal and why:

> Due to the voting fraud and duplicate accounts used to falsify the level of interest in this proposal, the "Crowd Machine" proposal has been closed retroactively. Please refrain from creating additional accounts in the future. Crowd Machine is no longer welcome to submit an application to create a Stack Exchange site. – Robert Cartaino♦

As long as you're not doing this, you're probably going to be just fine!

So, share with your friends and family; advertise on your blog or twitter! Make that proposal successful!